# how to count values in columns for identical elements

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
|          id|     column1|      column2|
+------------+------------+-------------+
|           1|           1|            5|
|           1|           2|            5|
|           1|           3|            5|
|           2|           1|           15|
|           2|           2|            5|
|           2|           6|            5|
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

How to get the maximum value of column 1? And how to get the sum of the values in column 2?
To get this result:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
|          id|     column1|      column2|
+------------+------------+-------------+
|           1|           3|           15|
|           2|           6|           25|
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`.groupBy`** and agg (**`max(column1),sum(column2)`**) for this case

```
#sample data
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,1,5),(1,2,5),(1,3,5),(2,1,15),(2,2,5),(2,6,5)],["id","column1","column2"])

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupBy("id").\
agg(max("column1").alias("column1"),sum("column2").alias("column2")).\
show()
#+---+-------+-------+
#| id|column1|column2|
#+---+-------+-------+
#|  1|      3|     15|
#|  2|      6|     25|
#+---+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is `groupBy` to group corresponding values of `id` and use aggregate functions `sum` and `max` with `agg`

The functions come from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` package.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val input = Seq(
        (1, 1, 5),
        (1, 2, 5),
        (1, 3, 5),
        (2, 1, 15),
        (2, 2, 5),
        (2, 6, 5)
   ).toDF("id", "col1", "col2")

val result = input
        .groupBy("id")
        .agg(max(col("col1")),sum(col("col2")))
        .show()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with sql then below is the sql version using `group by` , `max` and `sum` functions

```
import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val input = Seq(
    (1, 1, 5),
    (1, 2, 5),
    (1, 3, 5),
    (2, 1, 15),
    (2, 2, 5),
    (2, 6, 5)
  ).toDF("id", "col1", "col2").createTempView("mytable")

spark.sql("select id,max(col1),sum(col2) from mytable group by id").show
```

Result :

```
+---+---------+---------+
| id|max(col1)|sum(col2)|
+---+---------+---------+
|  1|        3|       15|
|  2|        6|       25|
+---+---------+---------+
```